# Как сделать текст прижатый к низу блока со скроллом?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок высотой 200px. В нем текст. Текст всегда прижат к низу блока. Но если текста много и он не помещается в 200px - появляется скролл. Как такое сделать? (высота блока может меняться)

Comment: Используй flex для прижатия текста к низу

Comment: вопрос то был не в том как прижать текст к низу)

Answer (score 1):

Добавить `overflow-y: auto`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.box p {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, alias.
  </p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, aperiam id est perferendis, excepturi necessitatibus fugiat quam. A fugiat reprehenderit, totam animi rem facilis obcaecati doloremque magnam omnis est quas saepe libero at, dolor nam sequi.
    Temporibus at, tempore officiis numquam quos quo distinctio natus quisquam mollitia ad eum repellendus.
    <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, aperiam id est perferendis, excepturi necessitatibus fugiat quam. A fugiat reprehenderit, totam animi rem facilis obcaecati doloremque magnam omnis est quas saepe libero at, dolor
    nam sequi. Temporibus at, tempore officiis numquam quos quo distinctio natus quisquam mollitia ad eum repellendus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример с использованием `display: table`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.block {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.block-inner {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
}

.block-text {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
    <div class="block-text">

      <p>Как сделать текст прижатый к низу блока со скроллом?</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще через `position: relative; top: 100%;`:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Some text</span>
  <p> Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Только надо учитывать, что `<p> Lorem ipsum</p>` должен находиться последним внутри родительского элемента, т.к. место которое он занимал остаётся за ним и появляется пустота, т.к. при `position: absolute;` и `position: fixed;` элемент выпадает из потока документа и не влияет на окружающие элементы, а при `position: relative;` он остаётся в потоке документа и как бы резервирует место. Почитать про это всё: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score -1):

Сам спросил, сам ответил) Вообще интересная задача. Можно ее на собеседованиях задавать. Кажется простой, но нет.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем тут вообще div?

Comment: вместо overflow-y: scroll; используйте overflow-y: auto;

Comment: простите, а на какую должность собеседуют, можно поинтересоваться? ))